# google translate api returned an error "The remote server returned an error: (403)"

Tags: c#, asp.net, webclient, http-status-code-403, google-translate

In c# i have used a code ,

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient()) 
{ 
   wc.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1)  AppleWebKit/537.36 " + "(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36");
   text = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(wc.DownloadData(url)); 
}
```

where 'url' contains google api url along with key & other credentials.
But , i am getting this error "The remote server returned an error: (403)" on calling DownloadData function.
On local machine it works fine but when we run it on server it is showing above error.

Comment: That means you are not authenticated.

Comment: sir but I m getting no such error while doing on local host. i have different keys for local machine and live website. i am using live website key which is configured using IP address of server hosting website. are there any configuration on hosting environment that need to be done. if you know any anything about this it would be helpful